# SVG childNodes return text

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I have an inline SVG and try to loop over all paths within a group element. When using `childNodes` I found out that Browsers add an extra `text` child for every path. I am curious why browsers are doing so and if there is a smart way to just loop over *real* child elements.

I've created a little JSBin to demonstrate the behaviour: http://jsbin.com/tutisakege/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

(Check the output of the console)

**HTML**

```
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g id="test">
    <path d="M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 Z" />
    <path class="red" d="M25 0 L25 25 L75 0 L75 25 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
var group = document.querySelector('#test'),
    children = group.childNodes;
```

The `children`object now holds **5** entries even though my test group only has **2** paths.

**Note:** I know I could loop over all entries and check whether I have an instance of `SVGPathElement` but that seems a but cumbersome to me.

(I've tested it in the latest Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers didn't add it, they are right there in the document source. There is whitespace between the path elements i.e. carriage returns and spaces.

You can skip the text by using [element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) but that apparently only works on Firefox and Chrome so if you want it done portably you'll probably need to stick with checking for element instances as you suggest in the question.

Comment: You are my hero~!!